# Storing polish characters utf8 doctrine 2 PHP, MySQL, Zend Framework

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, doctrine-orm

I have a CMS application written using the Zend Framework that allows you to translate the content. This works perfectly for German and French characters but is struggling with Polish, I've set up the database and connections correctly (as far as I can tell) but I'm still getting garbage stored and returned for Polish. The database is utf8_general_ci and so is the field. Doctrine connection params:
resources.entityManager.connection.charset = "utf8"
resources.entityManager.connection.default.parameters.driverOptions.1002 = "SET NAMES 'UTF8'"

The page with the database form posting the translation has:
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); (at top)
    [meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf8" /] (in head tags)

I have no additional encoding on the string that saves to the databse (doctrine 2):

```
 $cn->setContent($pageForm->getValue($field));
```

So, French and German are quite happy with this, but the following Polish:
specjalisty w produkcji zawieszeń, szybkość

Stores and views as:
specjalisty w produkcji zawieszeÅ„, szybkoÅ›Ä‡

I'm going round in circles with this one so any thoughts would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual issue was how I was setting utf8 in Doctrine 2. I connect via an Entity Manager and the settings needed to go there rather than Bootstrap or application.ini

```
'charset' => 'utf8', 'driverOptions' => array(1002=>'SET NAMES utf8')
```

Answer (score 6):

Setting `'charset'  => 'utf8'` in `orm_default` in config solved the problem in my case.

```
<?php
return array(
    'doctrine' => array(
        'connection' => array(
            'orm_default' => array(
                'driverClass' => 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver',
                'params'      => array(
                    'host'     => 'localhost',
                    'user'     => 'dbuser',
                    'password' => 'dbpass',
                    'dbname'   => 'dbname',

                    'charset'  => 'utf8',
                 // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                )
            )
        ),
        'driver'     => array(
            'zfcuser_entity' => array(
                'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
                'paths' => 'module/Application/src/Application/Entity',
            ),
            'orm_default'    => array(
                'drivers' => array(
                    'Application\Entity' => 'zfcuser_entity',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'zfcuser'  => array(
        'user_entity_class'       => 'Application\Entity\User',
        'enable_default_entities' => false,
    ),
);
```

Comment: can you please provide a way to force collate when generating database from doctrine console via orm:schema-tool:update?

Comment: @MarcelDjaman can You please confirm if adding `'driverOptions' => array(1002=>"SET NAMES 'UTF8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci'")` after `'charset'  => 'utf8',` solves your problem?

Comment: sorry i can reproduce it right now but what can i say i end it with `'driverOptions' => array(1002=>'SET NAMES utf8')` only

Comment: This works for me, Just For more accurate solution description, the configuration should be added under "params" under "orm_default" under "connection" under "doctrine", in the text above it's mentioned under "orm_default" which is not accurate.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, depending on you how you set up Doctrine with Zend Framework, the following line in application.ini may solve this for you:

```
doctrine.connectionParameters.charset = "UTF8"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following to aid debugging

```
$strBefore = 'specjalisty w produkcji zawieszeń, szybkość';
putdb($strbefore);
$strAfter = getdb();
var_dump($strBefore === $strAfter, $strBefore, $strAfter);
echo base64_encode($strBefore);
echo base64_encode($strAfter);
```

Comment: Thanks will try that and let you know.

Comment: Here is the output from the debug:


`bool(false) string(46) "specjalisty w produkcji zawieszeń, szybkość" string(76) "specjalisty w produkcji zawieszeÃ…â€ž, szybkoÃ…â€ºÃ„â€¡" c3BlY2phbGlzdHkgdyBwcm9kdWtjamkgemF3aWVzemXFhCwgc3p5YmtvxZvEhw==
c3BlY2phbGlzdHkgdyBwcm9kdWtjamkgemF3aWVzemXDg+KApsOi4oKsxb4sIHN6eWJrb8OD4oCmw6LigqzCusOD4oCew6LigqzCoQ==`

Answer (score 0):

I've checked right now displaying from db the string at polish language "specjalisty w produkcji zawieszeń, szybkość" and it's looking good. (zf 1.11, doctrine 1.2)

Try add in _initDoctrine() function

```
$conn->setCharset('utf8');
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. My connection is made in an EntityManager so I've added there:

    `$options = array(
       'connection' => array(
          'driver'   => "{$config->connection->driver}",
          'host'     => "{$config->connection->host}",
          'dbname'   => "{$config->connection->dbname}",
          'user'     => "{$config->connection->user}",
          'password' => "{$config->connection->password}",
          'charset' => "utf8"
          
        )
      );`

But this had no effect.

Comment: I've added the same polish text using zend_db and it's fine, so all I can assume is that there's an issue with doctrine 2.0 or my config with doctrine 2. I have set charset to utf8 though. At least I know the db is fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

config/packages/doctrine.yaml

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
    charset: UTF8
    options:
        1002: "SET NAMES 'UTF8' COLLATE 'utf8_polish_ci'"
```